# Two rewrite rules don't cooperate

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to rewrite two things on one site.

```
mysite.com/something -> mystie.com/index.php?s=something
```

and

```
mysite.com/something/another -> mysite.com/index.php?s=something&d=another
```

This is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?s=$1&d=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Separately both work but together they don't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that you're matching the '/' character in your first rule. Wouldn't the easiest solution be to simply add a character class to your rules, like:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?s=$1&d=$2 [L,QSA]
```

or simply change the order of the rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?s=$1&d=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the two rules. The rewrite engine goes through the file line by line, sequentially. The first rule you have:

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]

matches a url that has two name value pairs as well, so the file stop processing after the first match because you are using the L flag.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?s=$1&d=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I don't have time to test this for you, sorry.  But I'm feeling strongly that this is the problem. While I was writing this answer, someone gave pretty much the same advice. I thought of deleting my answer but want to make sure that you understood about the L flag and that the file is processed sequentially.

Comment: Like I stated in my answer this is correct. You can change order of the rules, but I would go for a characters class myself=)

Comment: I saw your answer as I was finishing my similiar answer. You beat me too it, but I wanted to make sure the person understood that the file is processed line by line. That bit me really bad a few years ago when I first started using rewriting and wanted to save them some pain.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.+)$ index.php?s=$1&d=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This works. Changing order didn't work. Also I forgot add that

```
mysite.com/something/another
```

the `another` string can be like asd-1231-ASDwqda .

Comment: In that case you should simple change the character class to `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` to match a-z in any case, numbers and the '-' character. Strange that reversing the rules didn't worked for you. Tried it locally and it worked fine for me.